# Problem with widgets and orientation in home application

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, widget

I am creating a home application and I finally got it to host widgets.  The only problem is that when I change the orientation of the phone the widgets disappear and I have to add them all over again.  I know that activities are recreated when the orientation changes but what should I do for the widgets to show up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setting the background of an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764086/setting-the-background-of-an-activity)

See my answer there. Just do not write anything in the `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

This is caused because the orintation changes restarts your activity.

Comment: Does this force the activity to not restart when changing the orientation?

Comment: Yep, if you do not add anything in onConfigurationChanged() method, basically you are telling you app: "DO NOT DO ANYTHING, IF ORIENTATION CHANGES" :D

Comment: But the problem is I have seperate layouts for landscape and portrait orientation.  Won't that be a problem?

Comment: And you load each based on orientation change? if you do change, then use the tests and when the orient is landscape load the landscape layout, and for portrait the portrait layout.

Comment: I think I might have found a better solution.  Is it possible to use the onconfigurationchanged() method on a specific view rather than the entire activity or layout?

Comment: You can affect that view from `onCC()`

Comment: If you have some particular view set it inside `LinearLayout` setting its initial orientation let say to portrait. And then you change the orientation of linearlayout using `.setOrientation()` in `onConfigurationChanged()` method.... Thus the view orientation. But if the whole (main) layout orientation changes then there is no need doing this.

Comment: Well the thing is that I havr widvets in a particular view and that is the only virw that I want to control the onconfigurationchanged

Comment: I don't know if that is possible. Sorry.