# ToggleButton state is erased when you turn the screen (Android)

Tags: java, android

I want to make a table binary which can change the bits and then to check if these are correct.

The first problem is that when you rotate the screen bits are reset and no how to correct this.

I also would like to see if you can save the states of the tooglebutton in a table java, then check if your settings are correct, because the table is quite large and so far I do one at a time.

Thanks!

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:weightSum="11" >

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#222222"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="A2"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#222222"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="A1" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#222222"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="A0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D7" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D6" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D5" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D4" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D3" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D2" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D1" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2222FF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="D0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:weightSum="11">

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="11" >


            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="1" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="11">

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="1" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="11">

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="1" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="1" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="11" >

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="11">

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="0" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#E0E0E0"
                android:text="1" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCFF"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6851685/557179 for changes due to orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely need to save the state of each cell, and re-select them programatically in the `onCreate()` method because the activity is destroyed and recreated when the screen rotates.  See the caution at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html.  You can also do this in the `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Simply create a button on the .java for each tooglebottom and kept me well the state. I guess that saves the state each time it is pressed.

Thanks!