# How can I prevent a re-start of my app when the phone is rotated?

Tags: android, media-player, application-restart

In my app I don't want to restart a media player once it starts if the user rotates the phone. How can I prevent a re-start of my app when it is rotated because it stops the running sound file that is playing?

Please show me the code I need to add and where to add it.

Thanks.

Truly,
Emad

Comment: See this approach. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764086/setting-the-background-of-an-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redesign your application to play the music from a service instead of from your main activity. Your main activity can at any time be killed by the operating system if it decides it needs memory.

See [What is a service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService)

Comment: I'd just like to point out that a Service is not immune to being killed than an Activity is. I think your suggestion to use a Service is still valid, however. Since it will be a user-visible Service, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856767/android-keeping-a-background-service-alive-preventing-process-death

Comment: It is however less likely which is what you most likely want. But agreed a bit clumsily formulated.

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm going to see what makes this code at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm works since it uses a service to play a media file. If I can fiture it out I will apply it into my app. Thanks everyone for the fast replies.

Comment: Hi Richard, I tried the code but it had parts missing but did find a better one at http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html and it had everything I needed to get a working demo of the media file to play even when I moved the phone around from portrait to landscape. I will now get that into my app. Truly, Emad

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
  <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="VncCanvasActivity">
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode)