# Android: Save variables and settings on rotation

Tags: android, screen-rotation

Is there a way to save variables that are being changed in the code, when the screen rotates? Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loss of variables switching orientations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755354/loss-of-variables-switching-orientations)

Answer (score 3):

You can save values into the instanceState Bundle when stopping an activity and restoring it when you start it. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Read values from the "savedInstanceState"
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Save the values you need into "outState"
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on GSala's answer, this is sort of how I'd do it:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    String someString = "this is a string";
    savedInstanceState.putString(CONSTANT_STRING, someString);
    //declare values before saving the state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Then in your onCreate you can get values like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addContentView(R.layout.view);

        //Make sure to do this check otherwise someString will
        //cause an error when your activity first loads!
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            //Do whatever you need with the string here, like assign it to variable.
            Log.d("XXX", savedInstanceState.getString(STRING_CONSTANT));
        }
}
```

This way, you don't have to Override onRestoreInstanceState as well. Also, this can be done with just about any variable or object, not just strings.

See [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) for more information.