# Exception in onSaveInstanceState & ExoPlayer

Tags: android, debugging, exoplayer

At the begging I know to save/restore variables in the rotate process.
I need to store the state of **SimpleExoPlayer** whether play or paused

**ExoPlayer** doesn’t restore its state on rotation (even if it is on paused the video always starts playing on configuration change)
because I used this line of code

> mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

so in case of user clicked in pause and rotate the screen it still start

when I googled for this issue I found that I must use a boolean variable  instead of **true**

> mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);

but I found the mExoplaer variable with a null

the screen for debugging  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcSvL.png)

the screen of code in on saveInstance [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i446q.png)

the screen of retrieve of boolean variable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx7f8.png)

the screen of mExoPlayer init [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2Am.png)
then invoke this method in inCreateView

can anyone help me?

Comment: Also, your debugger says that exoplayer is null at the break. Are you getting a NullPointerException? If not, then post the Exception data as well in addition to the onSaveInstanceState method override. If you are getting NullPointerException, fix your exoplayer being null before adding data to the outState Bundle.

Comment: you probably don't save your instance variables, take a look at this question among others : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121761/android-save-variables-and-settings-on-rotation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Save variables and settings on rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121761/android-save-variables-and-settings-on-rotation)

Comment: check the second image,

Comment: yes i get NullPointerException so that i ask for help as in side method the player value equal to null outside of method it allocated to memory location

Comment: How are you maintaining the mExoPlayer variable? Are you setting it to null before rotation (or anywhere else in your code?)

Comment: @ReverseEffect not .. i just init it 
will edit post with pic for that

Comment: @ReverseEffect edited